# How to Delete Node From Firebase from TableView

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, tableview, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently using Firebase to store the data of people and some details about them. This is how I retrieve the details from the database to populate my tableView:

```
 let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users")
    ref.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock:
    { (snapshot) in

        if let firstname = snapshot.value?.objectForKey("firstname"), lastname = snapshot.value?.objectForKey("lastname")
        {
            let fullname = "\(firstname) \(lastname)"
            self.names.append(fullname)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }, withCancelBlock: nil)
```

Each of my users has their own unique ID, and I'm trying to delete them according to that. So far I delete my users only from the tableView end and not from the database:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    if editingStyle == .Delete
    {
        names.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

        //Delete from firebase
    }
}
```

In my observePeople() function I implemented the code to observe if a child is removed like so:

```
ref.observeEventType(.ChildRemoved, withBlock:
    { (snapshot) in

    if let firstname = snapshot.value?.objectForKey("firstname"), lastname = snapshot.value?.objectForKey("lastname"), dateOfBirth = snapshot.value?.objectForKey("Date of Birth"), zipcode = snapshot.value?.objectForKey("Zipcode")
    {
        print("We deleted the person \(firstname) \(lastname) with the details: \(dateOfBirth), \(zipcode)")
    }

    }, withCancelBlock: nil)
```

So how can I delete the exact user based on their ID when someone deletes them with a swipe from the tableView?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `removeValue()` method at the reference where you want to delete the user.

So in your `commitEditingStyle` table view method, where you wrote `//Delete from firebase` is where you could insert something like:

```
ref.child("Users/\(uniqueUserID)").removeValue()
```

You would need to get the `uniqueUserID` for the user at the `indexPath.row` that you deleted in your table view.

I can go into more detail if you type out an example of what your JSON tree looks like for your users.

Is it something like this?

```
"root"
    "Users"
        "uniqueUserID"
            "firstname"
            "lastname"
            "dateOfBirth"
            "zipcode"
```

**EDIT**
If your dictionary looks like what's above I would do something like this:

In `ref.observeEventType(.ChildAdded`:

```
//names will be the array that stores the user data that you retrieve from Firebase
//names will be an array of dictionaries
//each dictionary will represent a user object that includes firstname, lastname, AND uniqueUserID
self.names = [[String : AnyObject]]()//make a new clean array
//create a dictionary to store the user data
let user = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
//get the uniqueUserID which is the `snapshot.key`
let uniqueUserID = snapshot.key as! String
//add the uniqueUserID to the user dictionary
user["uniqueUserID"] = uniqueUserID as! String
self.name.append(user)
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

In the `commitEditingStyle` table view method where you wrote `//Delete from firebase`:

```
//get the user at the `index.row` in the names array
let user: [String: AnyObject] = self.names[indexPath.row]
let uniqueUserID = user["uniqueUserID"]
//get the uniqueUserID
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
//remove that user at that uniqueUserID
ref.child("Users/\(uniqueUserID)").removeValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to locate the snapshot's key which is the user's unique ID by matching the full names. I did however run into an error where after I delete an item it deletes the index after it until I get to one item remaining and I get the "Index out of Range error".

```
 let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users")
        ref.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

            if let firstname = snapshot.value?.objectForKey("firstname"), lastname = snapshot.value?.objectForKey("lastname")
            {
                let fullname = "\(firstname) \(lastname)"
                let currentName = self.names[indexPath.row]

                if fullname == currentName
                {
                    print("We have a match")
                    let currentKey = snapshot.key
                    ref.child(currentKey).removeValue()

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
                    {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }

            }

        }, withCancelBlock: nil)
```